# Use sed to remove multiple lines between 2 sets of characters

Tags: bash, sed

I'm using sed on a macOS X computer.

I have a set of very large financial 10-K files and I want to keep only the text.

Right now, I'm trying to remove all of the information between

```
<TYPE>XML
```

and

```
<DOCUMENT>
```

Usually there is a lot of information between the two but here is how a sample would look:

```
#Other things I want to keep
<TYPE>XML
<SEQUENCE>10
<FILENAME>rht-10qq3fy19_htm.xml
<DESCRIPTION>IDEA: XBRL DOCUMENT
<TEXT>
<XML>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xbrl
...
<DOCUMENT>
#Some other text I need to keep
```

I've been trying to use sed without much results, I can only get it to remove single line entries like

```
<TYPE>XML SOME WORDS SOME WORDS <DOCUMENT>
```

I used this code to get that to work:

```
sed -i '' s/<TYPE>XML.*<DOCUMENT>//g' filename.txt
```

What should I change to get the result I want?

Once I can solve this, the other things I need to clean should also be easier. The solution doesn't have to use sed.

I'm using `-i` and `''` at the beginning of the sed command because I'm on a Mac (BSD) and I'm modifying data in place.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I haven't misunderstood you, this will work for you:

```
sed '/<TYPE>XML/,/<DOCUMENT>/d' filename.txt
```

For anyone else looking for how to delete text between two patterns, use:

```
sed '/START_PATTERN/,/END_PATTERN/d' filename.txt
```